# updating Touchegg to latest version

Tags: linux, ubuntu, touchpad

i am trying to install Touchegg , i did follow this  guide [here](http://code.google.com/p/touchegg/wiki/CompileSourceCode),

---

however in the last step "sudo make install" iǘe get this error : `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgeis`

---

Tried to google around, but i have had not luck.

---

any help would be very welcome.

---

at the moment i am using a Ubuntu variant: elementaryOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is saying you are missing a library called *libgeis.so*. You should first of all search your system to check whether you do have such a library, somewhere in your system:

```
  find / -type f -name libgeis.so -print
```

If you cannot find it, then you should install a package called *libgeis-dev*,

```
  sudo apt-get install libgeis-dev
```

which should install the library in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgeis.so, or likewise for i686. If it still cannot find it, you should learn how to teach your compiler/loader to search for libraries in non-standard directories. Should you really feel lazy, this:

```
  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

will do it for you (careful if you have a 32bit system).

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Comment: @user281753 De nada, senor